# Sublime Text 3 won't restart after closing in Windows 7

Tags: sublimetext3, windows-7-x64

I have installed Sublime Text 3 (Build 3114) to Windows 7 (64 bit). It's working well. However, once I close the software, it won't relaunch. Has anyone experienced similar symptoms? Is there a solution or workaround?

Sublime Text 2 did not show the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround 1

Restart Windows 7 and Sublime Text 3 can be launched normally.

## Workaround 2

1. Open **Windows Task Manager**
2. I noticed that after closing Sublime Text 3, the Process Sublime Text 3 does not end and instead persists.
3. In order to relaunch Sublime Text 3, Select Sublime Text 3 in **Process** pane of **Windows Task Manager** and click the **End Process** button.
4. Now you can relaunch Sublime Text 3.